# Why does delegating to the default constructor not zero initialize member variable

Tags: c++11

```
#include <string>

struct T1 {
  int _mem1;
  int _mem2;
  T1() = default;
  T1(int mem2) : T1() { _mem2 = mem2; }
};
T1 getT1() { return T1(); }
T1 getT1(int mem2) { return T1(mem2); }
int main() {
  volatile T1 a = T1();
  std::printf("a._mem1=%d a._mem2=%d\n", a._mem1, a._mem2);
  volatile T1 b = T1(1);
  std::printf("b._mem1=%d b._mem2=%d\n", b._mem1, b._mem2);
  // Temporarily disable
  if (false) {
    volatile T1 c = getT1();
    std::printf("c._mem1=%d c._mem2=%d\n", c._mem1, c._mem2);
    volatile T1 d = getT1(1);
    std::printf("d._mem1=%d d._mem2=%d\n", d._mem1, d._mem2);
  }
}
```

When I compile this with gcc5.4, I get the following output:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 test.cpp -o test && ./test
a._mem1=0 a._mem2=0
b._mem1=382685824 b._mem2=1
```

Why does the user defined constructor, which delegates to the default constructor not manage to set _mem1 to zero for `b`, however `a` which uses the default constructor is zero initialized?

Valgrind confirms this also:

```
==12579== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12579==    at 0x4E87CE2: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1631)
==12579==    by 0x4E8F898: printf (printf.c:33)
==12579==    by 0x4005F3: main (in test)
```

If I change if(false) to if(true)

Then the output is as you would expect

```
a._mem1=0 a._mem2=0
b._mem1=0 b._mem2=1
c._mem1=0 c._mem2=0
d._mem1=0 d._mem2=1
```

What is the compiler doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: for trivial types, the two distinct forms of "default construction" leads to two different initializations:

- `T a;` in which case the object is *default-initialized*. Its value is undetermined and *undefined behavior* will soon happen (this is how is initialized `b.mem1` and why valgrind detect an error.)
- `T a=T();` in which case the object is *value-initialized* and its entire memory is zeroed (this is what happens to `a.mem1` and `a.mem2`)

**Long answer**: Actualy, the default constructor of `T1` is not the cause of zero initialization of a.mem1. `a` has been first zero-initialized but not `b` because of a singular rule of the standard that does not apply for `b`'s initializer.

The definition `volatile a=T()` causes `a` to be [value-initialized](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#7) <sup>(1)</sup>. `struct T1` as no [user-provided](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.def.default#def:user-provided) default constructor <sup>(2)</sup>. For such a struct the entire object is [zero-initialized](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#5) as stated by this rule of the C++11 standard [[dcl.init]/7.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#7.2):

> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if T's implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.

---

There is a subtle difference between C++11 and C++17 that causes the definition `volatile b=T(1)` to be *undefined behavior* in C++11 but not in C++17. In C++11, `b` is initialized by copying an object type `T1` which is initialized by the expression `T(1)`. This copy construction evaluate `T(1).mem1` which is an *undetermined value*. This is [forbidden](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#12). In c++17, `b` is directly initialized by the *prvalue* expression `T(1)`.

The evaluation of this undetermined value inside the `printf` is also *undefined behavior* independently of the c++ standard. This is why valgrind complains and why you see inconsistent outputs when you change `if (true)` to `if (false)`.

<sup>(1) strictly speaking `a` is copy constructed from a value-initalized object in c++11</sup>

<sup>(2) T1's default constructor is not user provided because it is defined as defaulted on the first declaration</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**
The `default` constructor in your code is considered **trivial** and that kind of constructor perform no actions i.e. leave things unitialized.

**Longer answer**

> Trivial default constructor
>
> The default constructor for class T is trivial (i.e. performs no
>   action) if all of the following is true:
>
> ```
> The constructor is not user-provided (i.e., is implicitly-defined or defaulted on its first declaration)
> T has no virtual member functions
> T has no virtual base classes 
>
> T has no non-static members with default initializers.
> ```
>
> (since C++11)
>
> ```
> Every direct base of T has a trivial default constructor
> Every non-static member of class type has a trivial default constructor
> ```
>
> **> A trivial default constructor is a constructor that performs no
>   action.** All data types compatible with the C language (POD types) are
>   trivially default-constructible. Unlike in C, however, objects with
>   trivial default constructors cannot be created by simply
>   reinterpreting suitably aligned storage, such as memory allocated with
>   std::malloc: placement-new is required to formally introduce a new
>   object and avoid potential undefined behavior.

http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/language/default_constructor.html

Comment: Why then is 'a' zero initialized if the default constructor does nothing.

Comment: @jonynz when default constructor is called A a() it is called value initialisation which does zero initialisation before calling default construction. if you call A a; it will not be zero initialised (same as delegating contsructor).

Comment: @code707, are you referring to: "if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;" as part of: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization for a?
Then for b, the following " if T is a class type with at least one user-provided constructor of any kind, the default constructor is called;" occurs right?

Comment: Yes exactly. Basically it means that when you are handling construction compiler wont zero initialize but when compiler handle it will do.

Comment: This answer is too simple. Not every `default`ed constructor is trivial. In particular, a defaulted constructor is not trivial when one of the members had a non-trivial default constructor. (But in the example given, there are no such members, and therefore `T1::T1` is trivial)

Comment: sorry for the delay, this answer still doesn't explain why:volatile T1 a = T1(); is zero initialized but not volatile T1 b = T1(1);